# Provide specific example for block variation

Tags: javascript, block-editor

I'm generating block variations on top of the "native" Gutenberg blocks (eg. `core/***`).
For example, I have a "catchphrase" block, which is a variation of the paragraph block (`core/paragraph`):

```
import { addFilter } from "@wordpress/hooks";

const paragraphSettings = (settings, name) => {
  if (name !== "core/paragraph") {
    return settings;
  }
  settings.variations = [{
      icon: "sticky",
      name: "catchphrase",
      title: "Catchphrase title",
      description: "Catchphrase description",
      attributes: {
        variation: "catchphrase"
      },
      isActive: (blockAttributes, variationAttributes) => { 
        return blockAttributes.variation === "catchphrase"
      }
    }]
  return settings;
}

addFilter(
  "blocks.registerBlockType",
  "gracietco-gut/supports/paragraph",
  paragraphSettings
);
```

So far, this works great: the variation appears in the block inserter and is fully functional.

I want to go further and provide a different example for my catchphrase block & the paragraph block. As stated in the [official WP documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-variations/), we can supposedly use the `example` field to achieve this:

> example (optional, type Object) – Example provides structured data for the block preview. You can set to undefined to disable the preview shown for the block type.

So I tried to add the following to the variation object:

```
example: {
  attributes: {
    variation: "catchphrase",
    content: "This is a catchphrase."
  }
},
```

This way, `settings.variations` looks like this:

```
settings.variations = [{
      icon: "sticky",
      name: "catchphrase",
      title: "Catchphrase title",
      description: "Catchphrase description",
      attributes: {
        variation: "catchphrase"
      },
      example: {
        attributes: {
          variation: "catchphrase",
          content: "This is a catchphrase."
        }
      },
      isActive: (blockAttributes, variationAttributes) => { 
        return blockAttributes.variation === "catchphrase"
      }
    }]
```

Unfortunately, the example of the variation is not changed. I even tried to set the example field to undefined, but the example is still here, showing the `core/paragraph` example.

I'm running WP 5.9 on a fresh install.

Does this feature even work? Is there something I am missing? Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: If anyone want to follow up on this, I created an issue on Gutenberg GitHub repo: https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/38279